# Steganography CTF question

Tags: decryption, encoding, steganography, ctf

I have recently participated in a CTF competition and failed in the following stage where the solution was never revealed.

After a really hard job I got access to a text file that contains a really strange set of letters which should guide me through the next stage.

Some of the text is:

> OOOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMMMmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomOoMoOmoOmoomOo
> MMMmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomOoMoOmoOmoomOoMMMmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomOo
> MoOmoOmooOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoO
> MMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoO
> MoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOo

Any ideas of what I can do with it? I am really interested in learning new things and knowing how this should have been solved

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be **COW**.

[COW programing language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/COW)

> The COW programming language is an esoteric programming language
> created by Sean Heber in 2003. It is a Brainfuck variant designed
> humorously with Bovinae in mind. COW has twelve instructions (four
> more than Brainfuck) and is Turing-complete. Most instructions are
> moos, only the capitalization varies: mOo, moO, mOO, Moo, and so on.
> MMM, OOO, oom and OOM are the exceptions. All other character
> combinations are ignored and treated as comments.

Here is Javascript Interpreter for COW, [COW Interpreter](https://frank-buss.de/cow.html)

Your sample translates to "**t**", just the letter **t**.

Comment: Thanks, But it got me the following result (using the full code):

Comment: this is how i like my salads: 
oa wugtpcog ku FwemaFgdwiFwem, hkpf og

Comment: any idea of what can be done with the second part of the sentence?

Comment: @user245607 That second part is a simple caeser cipher with a shift of 24

Comment: @user245607 - as *nobody* stated, it's ROT24 (a.k.a. *Caesar shift 24*) and decodes to: **my username is DuckyDebugDuck, find me**